# How to escape a filter variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to escape the single quotes in the unique filter in angular but I can't, I've tried it in the following ways. If the field wouldn't have a hyphen I could do attrbutes.displayname and it will work (I've tried it), but I have a hyphen...

Example:

```
<select ng-model="style" ng-options="block.attributes['display-name'] for (blockName, block) in styleBlocks | unique:'attributes[\'display-name\']'">

<select ng-model="style" ng-options="block.attributes['display-name'] for (blockName, block) in styleBlocks | unique:'attributes[\\'display-name\\']'">
```

Comment: why you don't create a function in your controller or create a custom filter for this complex queries, it would be cleaner. Don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I prefer to use standard and well-tested functionalities.

Comment: A $filter, as @Dalorzo suggests, is in fact the standard and well-tested (and maintainable, and readable, and....) way to do anything other than the most basic filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode escape `\u0027` for single quotes:

```
'attributes[\u0027display-name\u0027]'
```

**References**

- [Unicode support was introduced in JavaScript 1.3](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/000126.html)
- [ECMAScript 2015: Table 34 — String Single Character Escape Sequences](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-34)
- [AngularJS source: parseSpec.js - "it should tokenize unicode"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/parseSpec.js#L123)
- [Canonicalization, locale and Unicode](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode)